# ggplot and errorbars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a plot with errorbars from the following data (dput of the dataframe in the end). I'd like to create errorbars for the "est A" and "est B" variables for each "loc", but I cannot figure out the right way to melt/cast the data so that each "loc" would have two rows with several columns.

I.e. I'd like to convert the dataframe into

loc est value  lb     ub

a    A   0.56   0.26  1.20

a    B   0.26   0.11  0.60

b    A   0.13

b    B   0.03

c    A

c    B

```
ggplot(test,aes(x=Loc,y=value,color=est))+geom_point()+geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=ub,ymin=lb))


> dput(test)
structure(list(Loc = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s"), `est A` = c(0.563270934055709, 
0.137109873453407, 0.0946514679398302, 0.185103062070327, 0.0322566231880829, 
0.122509922923046, 0.120243043198876, 0.496530499385046, 0.469200921538171, 
0.0605252215342125, 0.102364314964088, 0.115500654388976, 0.226320301860998, 
0.553299923910439, 0.0284461712437990, 0.161231809656951, 0.129270683014873, 
0.0691902563736868, 4.22775563209408e-10), `est B` = c(0.261222076585074, 
0.0361169058045732, 0.0389295009573361, 0.0341489915400374, 0.00722206105211422, 
0.0756192543690879, 0.0638910584951127, 0.112923798991901, 0.169215410079679, 
0.0235142527703486, 0.0347964005083873, 0.0485649792804626, 0.057534910753763, 
0.142573116854277, 0.0221769276223588, 0.104198059736499, 0.0234801538140553, 
0.072563099770018, 1.93211916678252e-10), `A lb` = c(0.262976608413878, 
0.0724138165552355, 0.0496821188642757, 0.083935851825787, 0.00630380846921399, 
0.0490562081838664, 0.0467393615329014, 0.20284436584412, 0.178474018619480, 
0.0171506568665928, 0.0503363150211533, 0.0600281091658352, 0.0747597162489745, 
0.276929613768523, 0.00665167561787145, 0.0580348444006193, 0.0516432163190537, 
0.0228220757228112, 0), `A ub` = c(1.20647287629726, 0.259606775235633, 
0.180324442434493, 0.408206300913301, 0.165057321233572, 0.305948661143090, 
0.309340756132258, 1.21542708762748, 1.23351010121895, 0.213595459944227, 
0.208168853315217, 0.222235904972905, 0.685140094216929, 1.10548237017075, 
0.121651250740107, 0.447932560408103, 0.323583825296458, 0.209765826526966, 
Inf), `B lb` = c(0.111866193520147, 0.0169169666997800, 0.0186761266424921, 
0.0121471488870159, 0.00126380823047679, 0.0279532804037691, 
0.0225442254744942, 0.0369377660459994, 0.0509571176650792, 0.00592607390737984, 
0.0157043256006381, 0.0231925392578512, 0.0153998561264800, 0.0612241780775462, 
0.00507024995333768, 0.0364091610491575, 0.00745586930827693, 
0.0243798413908829, 0), `B ub` = c(0.609987442570209, 0.0771078472899858, 
0.0811466999446844, 0.0960022499146318, 0.0412706331409062, 0.204565315724654, 
0.181069310198491, 0.345223486522794, 0.561920617187038, 0.0933029341161755, 
0.0770991075408484, 0.101694652159027, 0.214954342966326, 0.332010886676128, 
0.0970003694676995, 0.298200654450461, 0.0739441103828987, 0.215973654783605, 
Inf)), .Names = c("Loc", "est A", "est B", "A lb", "A ub", "B lb", 
"B ub"), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I called your dataframe Data, then:

```
test <- with(Data,
   data.frame(
     Loc = rep(Loc,2),
     est = rep(c("A","B"),each=nrow(Data)),
     value = c(get("est A"),get("est B")),
     lb = c(get("A lb"),get("B lb")),
     ub = c(get("A ub"),get("B ub"))
   )
)
ggplot(test,aes(x=Loc,y=value,color=est))+geom_point()+
     geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=ub,ymin=lb))
```

And please, never ever use variable names with a space if possible. If you didn't, you could just have done:

```
test <- with(Data,
   data.frame(
     Loc = rep(Loc,2),
     est = rep(c("A","B"),each=nrow(Data)),
     value = c(estA,estB),
     lb = c(Alb,Blb),
     ub = c(Aub,Bub)
   )
)
ggplot(test,aes(x=Loc,y=value,color=est))+geom_point()+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=ub,ymin=lb))
```

Comment: Thx. But is there an easier way to accomplish the same thing using the reshape package??

Comment: @Misha: This is way easier than the reshape package if you ask me. You make a vector with Locs, one with est, and then you just paste the data together. If you insist on using reshape, you'll have to use a seperate melt for value, lb and ub, and then rename the created variable "variable", and then paste everything together using a merge. Sure you want to do that?

Comment: @Joris: So its just noe me not getting reshape then.. Thx a mill. Misha

Comment: Great answer!  You've opened my eyes to the use of 'with' and 'get'.

Comment: @Joris: Agreed that spaces are bad but you can avoid calls to `get` by using backquotes, e.g., `Data$\`est A\``

Comment: @Richie : try that within a `with` construct... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use the reshape package, I found following solution (assuming that your data frame's variables are named w/o spaces):

```
head(df)

  Loc       estA        estB         Alb       Aub         Blb        Bub
1   a 0.56327093 0.261222077 0.262976608 1.2064729 0.111866194 0.60998744
2   b 0.13710987 0.036116906 0.072413817 0.2596068 0.016916967 0.07710785
3   c 0.09465147 0.038929501 0.049682119 0.1803244 0.018676127 0.08114670
4   d 0.18510306 0.034148992 0.083935852 0.4082063 0.012147149 0.09600225
5   e 0.03225662 0.007222061 0.006303808 0.1650573 0.001263808 0.04127063
6   f 0.12250992 0.075619254 0.049056208 0.3059487 0.027953280 0.20456532

test <- data.frame(cbind(melt(df[,1:3]), lb=c(df$Alb, df$Blb), ub=c(df$Aub, df$Bub)))
ggplot(test2,aes(x=Loc,y=value,color=variable)) + geom_point() + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=ub,ymin=lb))
```

You just melt the est-columns and bind the melted data frame with catenated lower/upper bounds columns.